# If I write a library for JavaScript golfing, can I use it

Tags: discussion

For example, if I wanted to use Jquery with my JavaScript answer, can I? What do I title the language? JavaScript, JavaScript (with Jquery)?

And what if I write my own library that has tools to make golfing easier? Is this allowed?

If it isn't allowed, can I use it so long as I include the library's total byte length with my code's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can use libraries

If you want to use Jquery with Javascript, saying something like "Javascript with Jquery" as your language in your answer is fine.

If you want to make your own library, that's totally allowed. As long as the library is somewhere other people can see it, it's fine. Just say "Javascript with MyLibrary" as your language.

Just remember that your library should be specified and made public before the question is asked.

You should not count the bytes in the library as bytes of your code. They are part of the language.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Do I need to add the byte-count of my library to the byte-count of my code?

Comment: @EliR No, you do not.